# Is there a default public chrome-cast receiver we can use?

Tags: google-cast

From Google's documents we are asked to setup our own web server to host the receiver.html.

Is there a default public chrome-cast receiver that can be used by any one?

I just need the very basic receiver, the same as the receiver.html that provided in the CastSample, but I don't want to run my own server to host this simple file.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have python running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]` could do the trick.

Comment: I don't want something that running on my own server. I really want a public server so that when I publish my app, I don't need my own server running.

Answer (score 2):

There is another simple way to do this. There is a site called pastehtml.com, where you can host a simple html for free and stays forever. You can even edit it whenever you want. Just now created mine, but I havent yet submitted it to google. Will keep you posted, once I get an approval or rejection from google on my device's whitelisting.

Comment: I have to admit. This is not a good soln. It might work for easier development and lesser hastle. But its not reliable in my experience. The site has been too flaky. But for development purpose, its the simplest soln.

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast receivers are tied to a URL, so I don't see how there could be a public one for a custom application, unless someone publishes a receiver that offers a service that your sender needs.

Bear in mind that the receiver needs to be publicly hosted on the web, but it doesn't not need to be dynamically generated. You could, for example, upload your html/css/js files to Amazon S3 and configure it to serve them very cheaply. There are probably other places where you can host files and have them served over http for minimal cost.

Comment: I am wondering if Google could provide such a public receiver with the basic functionality (like the receiver.html in their Sample) that could be used by everyone.                                      Do you know why Chromecast can't get the receiver from the client but has to be from a http server?

Comment: It is just not how it is supposed to work. Receivers are supposed to provide certain services and functionality to clients. For example, YouTube receiver can queue and play YouTube videos. The receiver is not necessarily tied to a client. Any client could connect to Chromecast and use the YouTube API - it doesn't have to be the YouTube client. If you want to implement a new type of receiver, then it has to be hosted on the web. Maybe you could explain what you want your receiver to do.

Comment: I would like a receiver that has the basic functionality to just play a given media. If the receiver is not tied to a client, is it possible for my client to use YouTube receiver without hosting my own YouTube receiver?

Comment: The reason why you won't get a basic receiver that anyone can use is that the receiver also has to be able to access the media you want to cast. If you just want to be able to cast YouTube videos, then yes -- you can use the YouTube receiver that already exists. If you want to be able to cast your own videos, though, you'll have to create your own receiver on a public server, as well as allow that receiver to access your media to stream to the clients.

Comment: I wonder if there's a possibility that in a future release Google could allow a user to use an internal host on their network for the receiver. I can imagine someone selling a NAS device that has a receiver page for watching media stored on it. In fact, it wouldn't be hard to do using a custom DNS mapping on an internal network if you could get your appId registered.

Comment: I am actually trying to cast my local videos hosted on my NAS server to Chromecast but without any luck. Chromecast does not support SAMBA.